# Android Studio fails to generate essential project files

Tags: android, android-studio

When I used Android Studio to make some projects, Activity.java, R.style, Manifest file and some other essential files are not generated.

I searched Google, but I was unable to find a solution for this problem. Has anyone encountered this problem before and come up with a solution?

Comment: R.java might not be generated because you have other errors in your code not related to the R file. So check if you have these errors, fix them, and clean your project.

Comment: Show the `MainActivity` code.

Answer (score 0):

Delete any import to an `R.java` class.
Move your cursor to a reference to any button/layout/string/whatever-coming-from-R, delete the last character, and hit `ctrl+space`. Eclipse will try to codehint you, automatically importing the correct `R.java`.
Just to keep it cool, clean and rebuild.

Comment: hmm actually I want to give you some picture, but I signed in just before so I can't upload image.
I have any MainActivity code. It isn't generated...T.T

Comment: Sorry for late reply.

Comment: I was busy at weekend.
anyway, I have no MainActivity Code. It ins't generated.

Comment: can I send you question by an e-mail?